# return unique records and the one with max datetime for non-unique records in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like below:

```
temp = [
(1676L, 530L, 'please submit your lab', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 10, 18), None),
(1677L, 527L, 'this is not the message youre looking for', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 27), None),
(1675L, 529L, 'hi. please come to my office at 5', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 10, 8), None),
(1678L, 529L, 'hi. please come to my office at 6', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 56), None),
(1674L, 528L, 'hi, my name is John', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 9, 40), None),
(543L, 527L, 'hi, this is message No 499', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 17, 53, 22), None)
(1630L, 527L, 'hi, I love you', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 28, 17, 50, 00), None)
]
```

the second item in the tuples is the ids (530,527,etc.) , and the fourth item is the datetime. there could be several records in the list with the same id (i.e. 2nd and the 6th and 7th records have the id = 527).

how can I write a code in python which returns unique records (their id showed up only once) and if they are not unique(there are multiple record with the same ids in the list), only return the one with maximum datetime?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using `dictionary` , taking the 2nd col as the key. Sort the list using the `datetime` column in `ascending order`. And since the key cannot be duplicates, you will have the value that is in the last (higher value if the key is same). To get the list, just access the `values` .

```
#sort by datetime [3] col
new_t = sorted(temp,key=lambda x: x[3])

#create dictionary with the [1] column as key
max_dict = { x[1]: x for x in new_t }

#get the required list
print([val for val in max_dict.values()])
```

#driver values

```
IN : 
temp = [ (1676L, 530L, 'please submit your lab', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 10, 18), None),
 (1677L, 527L, 'this is not the message youre looking for', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 27), None),
 (1675L, 529L, 'hi. please come to my office at 5', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 10, 8), None),
 (1678L, 529L, 'hi. please come to my office at 6', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 56), None), 
 (1674L, 528L, 'hi, my name is John', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 9, 40), None),
 (543L, 527L, 'hi, this is message No 499', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 26, 17, 53, 22), None),
 (1630L, 527L, 'hi, I love you', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 28, 17, 50, 00), None) ]

OUT :
[(1674L, 528L, 'hi, my name is John', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 9, 40), None), 
(1678L, 529L, 'hi. please come to my office at 6', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 56), None), 
(1676L, 530L, 'please submit your lab', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 10, 18), None), 
(1677L, 527L, 'this is not the message youre looking for', datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 29, 11, 50, 27), None)]
```

Comment: Thanks @tkhurana96 . Best part about this, I just learnt the thing about `dictionary` taking the `last value` for duplicate keys just a few hours ago when solving another problem.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Comment: Definitely an elegant solution, but I wonder if the OP will have trouble understanding lambda functions and list comprehension.

Comment: Have explained most of it. Will put in more explanation if required.

Comment: Glad to help @AminBeirami . Pls mark the answer if it satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like below.  It's not elegant, but its easy to understand.  Basically just make a dictionary where each item is a list of the tuples with the same id.  When inserting each tuple, check its date to see if its greater than the previous one.  This way, all of the tuples in the 'max' field are either unique, or have the greatest datetime.

```
r = {}
for t in temp:
    i = t[1]
    if not i in r:
        r[i] = {"max":t, "tuples":[t]}
    else:
        r[i]["tuples"].append(t)
        d1 = t[3]
        d2 = r[i]["max"][3]
        if d1 > d2:
            r[i]["max"] = t
```